# Flowable's callback not triggered when I delete last row in Room DB

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

I have query to Room DB:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(count*amount) FROM basket_items")
Flowable<Long> totalSum();
```

This query return total sum of  all rows. And I show this value in TextView.

```
Flowable<Long> totalSumData = basketRepository.getTotalSum();
        disposable = totalSumData.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(total -> {
                    if (total == null) {
                        totalSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
                    } else {
                        totalSum = new BigDecimal(total).divide(new BigDecimal(100), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                    }
                    callView(view -> view.setTotal(formatToLocaleString(totalSum)));
                });
```

When I delete one row from table - `Flowable` is triggered and `total` value is update. But when I remove last row in table and table is clear - total Flowable not  triggered as if nothing had happened. And I can not update total textView with new value(zero). I need get null or 0 in Flowable's callback when I delete last row in table

P.S When I use `LiveData` instead `Flowable` - I get `null` when I delete last row in table but with `Flowable` - as if nothing had happened.

Comment: I am not sure about your expectation with Flowable. Usually Flowable is preferred in this case: Handles when data is generated faster than it can be processed (called as Backpressure) . Is this your scenario? If not then • Single or Observable may do your purpose

Comment: I'm sure that I need Flowable. It work like Livedata. I used LiveData in my project but now I try change to rxJava. I have Fragment with table where data update after any change

Comment: Hi, Ive run into the same problem - I filed an issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123376277

Comment: Flowable as other Rx2 Publisher do not support null values, you need to tweek your SQL to return 0 instead of null when no rows...